# LARAVEL Como guardar datos dinamicos de una tabla HTML a Base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, array, matrices

buen dia, espero alguien pueda ayudarme con lo siguiente:
estoy usando una tabla en HTML con varios registros pero dentro de esa tabla estoy insertando inputs para alimentar mas informacion a la hora de capturar todo y enviarlo a la base de datos, mi dilema es que lo he logrado de una manera muy spaguetti y quiero mejorar este codigo, refactorizarlo, espero que alguien pueda darme una luz o apoyo si existe una forma mas limpia de hacerlo en laravel

TABLA HTML en la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table style="white-space: nowrap;" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-sm table-responsive-sm data-table" id="table-incidents">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Tramitar</th>
                        <th scope="col">Artículo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                        <th scope="col">No. OC.</th>
                        <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                        <th scope="col">Proveedor</th>
                        <th scope="col">Fecha Necesidad</th>
                        <th scope="col">Fecha Planta</th>
                        <th scope="col">Fecha Solicitada</th>
                        <th scope="col">Observacion</th>
                        <th scope="col">Linea</th>
                        <th scope="col">Categoria</th>
                        <th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
                        <th scope="col">Destino</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach($detail_requisition as $product)


                        <tr>         
                            <td> 
                                <input 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    name="chkproducto[{{$product->id}}]" 
                                    value="{{$product->id}}"
                                    id="chkproducto{{$product->id}}"
                                    > 
                            </td>                                
                            <td>
                                {{ $product->articulo }} 
                                <input type="hidden" 
                                        value="{{ $product->articulo }}" 
                                        name="articuloelegido[{{$product->id}}]">
                            </td>
                            <?php
                                $o_compra = DB::table('cp_ordenes_compras')
                                                    ->where('requicision_id', '=', $product->solicitudinterna)
                                                    ->where('cod_item', '=', $product->articulo)
                                                    ->first();
                                if (is_null($o_compra)) {
                                    $ordenCompra = '-';
                                    $cantidad = '-';
                                }else {
                                    $ordenCompra = $o_compra->orden_compra;
                                    $cantidad = $o_compra->cantidad;
                                }
                            ?>   
                            <td>{{ $cantidad }}</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ $ordenCompra }}
                                <input type="hidden" 
                                        value="{{ $ordenCompra }}" 
                                        name="ordencompra[{{$product->id}}]">
                            </td>                       
                            {{-- ========================================================= --}}                                    
                            {{-- =================== CAMBIAR EL ESTADO ================== --}}
                            <td style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                                <a type="button" 
                                        value="{{$product->id}}" 
                                        class="btn-sm btntable" 
                                        id="estado_selected" 
                                        data-toggle="modal" 
                                        data-target="#exampleModal_estado"                                            
                                    >
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                                <span id="estado_change{{$product->id}}">
                                    {{ $product->estado_producto }} 
                                </span>

                                <input type="hidden" 
                                        value="{{ $product->estado_producto }}" 
                                        name="estado[{{$product->id}}]" 
                                        id="estado_change_input{{$product->id}}">                                    
                            </td>
                            {{-- ========================================================= --}}    

                            {{-- ========================================================= --}}    
                            {{-- ================ CAMBIAR EL  PROVEEDOR ================== --}}
                            <td>
                                <a type="button" 
                                        value="{{$product->id}}" 
                                        class="btn-sm btntable" 
                                        id="product_selected" 
                                        data-toggle="modal" 
                                        data-target="#exampleModal"                                            
                                    >
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                                <span id="proveedor_change{{$product->id}}">
                                    {{ $product->proveedor_name }} 
                                </span>
                                <input type="hidden" 
                                        value="{{ $product->proveedor_name }}" 
                                        name="proveedor[{{$product->id}}]" 
                                        id="proveedor_change_input{{$product->id}}"
                                    >
                            </td>
                            {{-- ========================================================= --}}    

                            <td>                                    
                                <input type="date" 
                                        id="fecha_necesidad{{$product->id}}" 
                                        class="form-control"
                                        name="fecha_necesidad[{{$product->id}}]" 
                                        value="{{ $product->fecha_necesidad }}"
                                        onclick="chkfechas({{$product->id}})">                                                                     
                            </td>
                            {{-- fecha en planta --}}
                            <td>                                                        
                                <input type="date" 
                                        id="fecha_planta{{$product->id}}" 
                                        class="form-control"
                                        name="fecha_planta[{{$product->id}}]"                                             
                                        onclick="chkfechas({{$product->id}})"
                                        value="{{$product->fecha_planta}}"
                                        >                                                                     
                            </td>
                            <td>                                    
                                <input type="date" 
                                        id="fecha_solicitada{{$product->id}}" 
                                        class="form-control"
                                        name="fecha_solicitada[{{$product->id}}]"
                                        onclick="chkfechas({{$product->id}})"
                                        value="{{$product->fecha_solicitada}}"
                                        >                                                                     
                            </td>
                            {{-- ========================================================= --}}                            
                            {{-- ================= Agregar Observaciones ================= --}}
                            <td>
                                <div style="display:flex; width: 170px;">
                                    <a type="button" 
                                            value="{{$product->id}}" 
                                            class="btn-sm btntable" 
                                            id="obs_selected" 
                                            data-toggle="modal" 
                                            data-target="#exampleModal_obs"                                            
                                        >
                                        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <textarea 
                                        name="observacion[{{$product->id}}]" 
                                        id="obs_change_input{{$product->id}}" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        cols="40" 
                                        rows="1">{{$product->observacion}}</textarea>                                                                                
                                </div>    
                            </td>
                            {{-- ========================================================= --}}
                            <td>{{ $product->linea }} </td>
                            <td>{{ $product->categoria }} </td>
                            <td>{{ $product->precio_unitario }} </td>                                
                            <td>{{ $product->organizacion_destino }} </td>                                
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach            
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

CONTROLADOR en la funcion **tramitarlist** tomo cada array por tipo y usando la funcion **crearArrayTramite** combino todo en un array para luego recorrerlo y guardarlo en la base de datos, la funcion para combinar cada array separado es la que me tiene incomodo me parece que me ha quedado un mountruo horrible

```
 public function tramitarlist(Request $request)
    {
    
        //tipo de usuario
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $comprador_id = Auth::user()->dni;
        $comprador_name = Auth::user()->first_name;        

        $tipo_user = User::find($user_id)->roles->first();

       
         //categorias de compra 
        $categories = CategoryCompra::pluck('nombre', 'id');

        //productos de la REQUISICION elegida (para enviar a la vista)
        $detail_requisition = DB::table('cp_requisitions')
                                    ->where('solicitudinterna', $request->id_requisicion)
                                    ->get();
      

        //----------------------------------------------------------------//
        // FLUJO de COMPRA - COMPRADOR ACTUALIZA REQUISICIONES y GUARDA ENVIO del pedido al PROVEEDOR
        $id_requisicion     = $request->id_requisicion;
        $products_selected  = $request->chkproducto;    
        $observacion        = $request->observacion;
        $fecha_necesidad    = $request->fecha_necesidad;      
        $fecha_planta       = $request->fecha_planta;  
        $proveedor          = $request->proveedor;
        $estado_producto    = $request->estado;
        $ordencompra        = $request->ordencompra; 
        $articuloelegido    = $request->articuloelegido; 
        $fecha_solicitada   = $request->fecha_solicitada;

         
        // VALIDACION si existe un producto seleccionado
        if (!is_null($products_selected)) {
        
            //llama funcion creacion de array para el tramite        
            $productos_array = $this->crearArrayTramite($observacion, $fecha_necesidad, $fecha_planta, $proveedor, $estado_producto, $ordencompra, $articuloelegido, $fecha_solicitada);
                                
            //guardar los datos de los productos tramitados
            foreach ($productos_array as $key => $value) {                                                                                

                // ====== ACTUALIZAR -- REQUISICION ===========//
                $producto = Requisition::find($value['id']);  
                $producto->estado_producto      =   $value['estado'];
                $producto->estado               =   'En trámite por comprador';
                $producto->proveedor_id         =   $proveedor_dni;   
                $producto->proveedor_name       =   $value['proveedor'];                   
                $producto->comprador_id         =   $comprador_id;
                $producto->comprador_name       =   $comprador_name;
                $producto->fecha_necesidad      =   $value['fecha_necesidad'];
                $producto->fecha_planta         =   $fechaplanta;
                $producto->fecha_solicitada     =   $value['fecha_solicitada'];
                $producto->observacion          =   $value['desc'];
                $producto->save();                    
                                    
            }
                                                                                 
            // return ('productos para el tramite');
            return view('compras.requisitions.tramitarRequisitions')
         
        }       
    }
```

funcion para crear el array final, ya lo se es horrible un spaguetti pero trabajar con esos inputs en la tabla fue lo mas que mi cabeza pudo dar para guardar esos datos, que puedo hacer para refactorizarlo?:

```
 public function crearArrayTramite($observacion, $fecha_necesidad, $fecha_planta, $proveedor, $estado_producto, $ordencompra, $articuloelegido, $fecha_solicitada) {
        //realizar el flujo inicial de tramite
        //array para crear el objeto de productos elegidos para tramitar
        $productos_array = [];

        //crear el primer array con indices propios
        foreach ($observacion as $key => $value) {                
            array_push($productos_array, ['desc' => $value, 'id' => $key ]);                                        
        }

        //recorrer array con descripcion y id de producto
        foreach ($productos_array as $keyfull => $valuefull) {
            
            //recorrer el array de fechas con id
            foreach ($fecha_necesidad as $keyfecha => $valuefecha) {  
                
                foreach ($fecha_planta as $key_planta => $value_fecha_planta) {

                    //recorrer el array con estados de producto y id
                    foreach ($estado_producto as $keyestado => $value_estado) {

                        //recorrer el array con proovedor y id
                        foreach ($proveedor as $keyprov => $valueprov) {
                            
                            //recorre oel array con orden de compra y id
                            foreach ($ordencompra as $keyordencompra => $valueordencompra) {

                                //recorre ela rrray con articulo elegido y id
                                foreach ($articuloelegido as $keyarticuloelegido => $valuearticuloelegido) {

                                    //fecha solicitada que afectara la orden de compra
                                    foreach ($fecha_solicitada as $keyfecha_solicitada => $valuefecha_solicitada) {

                                        //validar si el id_producto de fechas es el mismo del array general y cargar la fecha
                                        if ($valuefull['id'] == $keyfecha) {                            
                    
                                            //cargar la fecha 
                                            $productos_array[$keyfull] = array_merge($productos_array[$keyfull], array('fecha_necesidad' => $valuefecha)); 
                                        }

                                        //validar si el id_producto de fecha de planta es el mismo del array general y cargar la fecha de planta
                                        if ($valuefull['id'] == $key_planta) {                                                

                                            //cargar la fecha 
                                            $productos_array[$keyfull] = array_merge($productos_array[$keyfull], array('fecha_planta' => $value_fecha_planta)); 
                                        }
                
                                        //validar si el id_producto de fechas es el mismo del array general y cargar la fecha
                                        if ($valuefull['id'] == $keyprov) {                            
                
                                            //cargar el proovedor
                                            $productos_array[$keyfull] = array_merge($productos_array[$keyfull], array('proveedor' => $valueprov)); 
                                        }
            
                                        //validar si el id_producto de estados es el mismo del array general y cargar el estado
                                        if ($valuefull['id'] == $keyestado) {                            
                
                                            //cargar el estado
                                            $productos_array[$keyfull] = array_merge($productos_array[$keyfull], array('estado' => $value_estado)); 
                                        }

                                        //validar si o-compra  es el mismo del array general y carga la o-compra al array madre
                                        if ($valuefull['id'] == $keyordencompra) {                            
                
                                            //cargar el estado
                                            $productos_array[$keyfull] = array_merge($productos_array[$keyfull], array('orden_compra' => $valueordencompra)); 
                                        }
                                        //validar si o-compra  es el mismo del array general y carga la o-compra al array madre
                                        if ($valuefull['id'] == $keyarticuloelegido) {                            
                
                                            //cargar el estado
                                            $productos_array[$keyfull] = array_merge($productos_array[$keyfull], array('articulo_elegido' => $valuearticuloelegido)); 
                                        }
                                        
                                        
                                        if ($valuefull['id'] == $keyfecha_solicitada) {                            
                
                                            //cargar el estado
                                            $productos_array[$keyfull] = array_merge($productos_array[$keyfull], array('fecha_solicitada' => $valuefecha_solicitada)); 
                                        }

                                    }                                        
                                }                                                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }  

        return $productos_array; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Normalmente las preguntas abiertas para discutir código terminan cerradas y/o con votos negativos por no apegarse a los lineamientos de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) al igual que las respuestas, pero mi consejo era demasiado largo para poner en un solo comentario

Algo que yo he hecho es utilizar un modal para hacer la edición e ingreso de datos en la tabla.

Puedes crear un botón "Crear" para abrir un modal con inputs para cada una de las columnas que tienes (Podría ser directamente a tu arreglo en lugar de tener la función para organizar los valores de todos los input en un arreglo).

En cada fila podrías agregar al final un pequeño botón de "Editar" (Yo usé un ícono de font awesome en lugar de texto para que el botón fuera pequeño) que abra el mismo modal, pero que al abrir obtenga los datos de la fila seleccionada y los muestre en los `inputs` del modal

Una forma muy sencilla de obtener una tabla que realice todas estas funciones mas ordenar los datos de acuerdo a una  o más columnas es utilizar livewire junto con laravel

Te recomiendo seguir [este tutorial](https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/s7-intro), fue creado por el desarrollador de livewire y es un ejemplo perfecto de cómo crear una tabla que sea funcional y bien organizada

Comment: Hola, mil disculpas por mi mal post, al inicio de la cuenta y el posteo te sale una mini guia de como deberia ser una buena pregunta, pense haberlo hecho bien. en fin

muchisimas gracias por la guia, lo del modal lo pense pero el lio es que el cliente quiere si o si todo en la tabla, intentare convencerle y seguir la guia de livewire, la otra es esa, el proyecto es laravel 7 y no tiene livewire, si me acepta el cliente el cambio tendria que darme al riesgo de usar livewire. seria igual muy inteligente aprender a hacer lo que hice de una mejor manera